# Deleting completed reminders

Tags: iphone, ios, ipados, reminders

Over time I end up with a lot of completed reminders, and I haven't found an easy way to delete them out. Right now I have to go into each reminder and delete it - something that is particularly cumbersome on the iPad, but easier on the iPhone.

**Is there an easy way to delete completed reminders, or have it do that automatically?**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove completed reminders in OS X and iOS](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/170696/remove-completed-reminders-in-os-x-and-ios)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an option in **`Settings > Mail, Contacts, Calendars`**

You can set it to only **Sync Reminders 2 Weeks Back**

That's the lowest value you can set.

Comment: Hmm. I had it set to one month back, but it seemed like it still had reminders that were more then one month old in there. Thanks. I'll try two weeks, and hopefully that will work.

Comment: I've just checked and I have completed reminders from February even though I also have "2 weeks back" selected. So it looks like it only work for "current" reminders, not completed ones.

Comment: That's what I was a little concerned about. I doubt that the completed reminders take up that much space, it just bothers me having them there.