# Remove completed reminders in OS X and iOS

Tags: macos, ios, icloud, reminders

I run the latest versions of OS X and iOS. Is there a way to mass-delete all completed reminders in both iOS and OS X? I’ve looked but can't seem to find a way so far.

Answer (score 13):

As of iOS 10.3.2, there is no way to do mass-delete reminders on iOS.

It is possible on macOS:

- Using the **Reminders** app in macOS Sierra, open the *Scheduled* list. Scroll up to reveal the **Show** button in the upper-right. Click that, then click the first completed reminder. Next, <kbd>⇧ shift</kbd>-click the last one. Go through your lists to delete completed reminders that had no due date.
- Using any desktop or laptop browser, you can visit the [iCloud web app](https://www.icloud.com/#reminders) and do the same. The only difference is the *Scheduled* list on the website does not allow you to mass-delete completed reminders.
- You can mass-delete reminders via AppleScript, using **Script Editor**.

The following script will delete all your completed reminders at once:

```
tell application "Reminders" to delete (reminders whose completed is true)
```

You could tweak this to delete only reminders that you completed some time ago:

```
set sixMonthsAgo to (current date) - 26 * weeks
tell application "Reminders" to delete (reminders whose completion date is less than sixMonthsAgo)
```

Save that script as an application and drop it in your `~/Applications` folder. Then you can delete your completed reminders with a simple click from **LaunchPad**, or even from the Dock.

If you wanted to get fancy you could then schedule a `LaunchAgent` to execute this script every night, then forget about it. ***With the usual caveat about running a program that deletes stuff automatically.***

Comment: If there is a large number of completed reminders the tell statement will need to be wrapped in a 'with timeout x seconds' clause, where x is a number of seconds large enough to allow time for all the reminders to be deleted.

Answer (score 11):

In OSX, go to Completed in Reminders, Click on the first one in the list, shift click on the last one, go to Edit menu and then Delete.

Comment: You can find completed reminders on macOS by scrolling up when viewing a reminders list.

Answer (score 2):

You can set it up in your Automator.

[image: delete]

You can be selective what is to be deleted by using find or filter action first.

Try it out.

Comment: Thank you for that. Is there any way to remove completed reminders from iOS too?

Comment: Did the answer solve your first question? if yes mark it as done, then post a new question about completed reminders. We like to have one question one answer so others can find it.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know you cannot do it in iOS 10.3 or in OS X 10.12, BUT... **you can do it on icloud.com**. Simply click on "completed reminders" to expand the list of completed reminders (translated from French icloud). You can then click "delete all completed reminders".

Answer (score 1):

You can use Apple's Shortcuts app to delete all completed tasks in Reminders (tested & work on iOS)
Here is the tutorial video:
https://youtu.be/kz02-OgYp7Q

Here is the screenshot of the video shows how to setup "Delete all completed tasks" button.
[image: Delete all completed tasks]

Comment: Answers on AD should be more than just links, please include enough details in your answer so that shows how to solve the problem. Links can break rendering your answer useless.

Comment: @nohillside : the details is `Apple's Shortcuts app`, that's the point of the answer, but it would be hard to understand if explain how to setup it in raw text, so the best way is the video.

Comment: A screenshot of the complete action would go a long way in explaining the solution, and would remain online even when the video gets removed.

Comment: @nohillside : I added the screenshot.